# Getting elementtree tag texts by partial tag names

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

In an XML document, I have an element with a `DateTime` tag, which can be extracted using:

```
for elem in xml_tree_root.iter(tag='DateTime'):
    print(elem.text)
```

in another version of the same XML file, the tag's name is `blahblooDateTimebloobli`. So I need something like:

```
for elem in xml_tree_root.iter(tag='*DateTime*'):
    print(elem.text)
```

that could work for both versions of the XML. But with the latter it doesn't work. It matches everything though, if I only put `'*'` which means in principle it must somehow work. My question is whether it is possible to feed regexp to elementtree `iter` search?

Comment: `*DateTime*` isn’t a regex. The documentation doesn’t make any reference that `iter(tag)` can use a regex or wildcard, so what makes you think this is possible?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=elementtree.iter#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.iter

Comment: as mentioned in the question, by putting `'*'`, which is a wildcard, you get all of the tags. So that made me think that might be possible, the question was, how?

Comment: What does the ElementTree documentation I linked to tell you about this? Is there any reference to using a wildcard or regex? It doesn’t make any such reference, does it?

Comment: ture. now.... how to solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe `print( [v for e in xml_tree_root.iter('*') if 'DateTime' in e.tag] )`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you simply want to get the text of any tags that contain the `DateTime` substring.

In this case, you can use

```py
values = [e.text for e in xml_tree_root.iter('*') if 'DateTime' in e.tag]
print(values)
```

That is, iterate over all the tags and if the tag name contains `DateTime`, get the node text value.

Comment: this answer is actually perfect, only thing is that I get the correct results if instead of `v` I write `e.text`. Then it works as expected.

Comment: @xaratustra Sure, that is what I had in my test. No idea where `v` came from.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [`element.iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) is clear:

> #### iter(*tag=None*)
>
> [...] If *tag* is not `None` or `'*'`, only elements whose tag equals *tag* are returned from the iterator.

So there is no support for wildcards, except for a complete joker: `'*'`.

If you know the two variants, then just chain two iterators:

```
from itertools import chain

for elem in chain(xml_tree_root.iter(tag='DateTime'), xml_tree_root.iter(tag='blahblooDateTimebloobli')):
    print(elem.text)
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this, it indeed works quite well.